# Deep animator wont install correctly

Tags: python

I've gotten a problem when I tried to install a piece of software called "Deep animator".
When I tried to install it (pip install deep_animator). I can't use the deep_animator tool because torch can't install. This was the result of it.

````
Collecting deep_animator
  Using cached deep_animator-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting Pillow==5.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-5.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting scipy==1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (31.1 MB)
Collecting torchvision>=0.2.1
  Using cached torchvision-0.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.3.0 (from deep_animator) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.3.0 (from deep_animator)```
````

Comment: As the error indicates, you probably don't have `pytorch` version>=1.3.0 installed on your machine. Check the requirements of the package and make sure they are satisfied

Comment: The issue is that there doesn't seem to be a version of `pytorch` that is supported for his type of machine, but if there is and `pip` just can't find it, manually installing could solve it.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to install pytorch now. I hope it works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, I have gotten another error.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\huubn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\huubn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\deep_animate.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\huubn\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\deep_animator\cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    from fastscript import call_parse, Param
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastscript'`

Comment: @Blenderer ```pip install fastscript ``` seems to do the trick